# Modelling a travelling wave

Tags: waves

Consider a 1-D duct. Standing wave in the duct can be represented as $$A(x)e^{i\omega t}$$ where A(x) is the amplitude( a function of direction) and $\omega $ is the frequency in Hz and $t$ time in s.

Similarly, is there a simple expression to represent a traveling wave in a duct?

To visualize standing wave I use [this applet](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/Physics-Interactives/Waves-and-Sound/Standing-Wave-Patterns/Standing-Wave-Patterns-Interactive). Setting different amplitudes for blue(right-running) and orange(left-running) wave gives a traveling wave(green wave). Is there an expression to express such traveling wave?

Answer (score 0):

For a plane wave in 1 dimension:
$$A(x)e^{i(\omega t - kx)}$$ where $x$ is the position and $k=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$ is the wave number.

Comment: $A(x)e^{i(\omega t - \kappa x)}$ can be written as $A(x)e^{i\omega t} e^{-i \kappa x} = B(x)e^{i\omega t}$ which represents a standing wave again. How does this represent a traveling wave?

Comment: The difference between a standing and  a traveling wave is if if you can separate the time and position factors completely.

Comment: So if you could write it as for example $A\sin(kx)\cos(\omega t)$ it would be a standing wave.

Comment: To get a better understanding, take a look at http://resonanceswavesandfields.blogspot.be/2008/01/superposition-and-standing-waves.html?m=1